# Google plus api: missing attachment on some posts

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-java-client, google-api-client, google-plus-domains

I've a problem with google domain api: when I get the list of activities of a user, for certain activity the attachment is missing.
Exactly, I can't see attachment for post like:
- google drive file links, for which google plus in his interface puts the document preview
- posts made by sharing something from another site, for example using +1 button on play store.

These are the steps to reproduce my issue. For this example I'll use google plus api standard, not the domain version, but also standard api have the same problem:

1) go to play store, share an app to Google+ using +1 button
2) go to https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list?hl=it, make a call to list service

As you can see, for the activitiy of point 1) there's no attachment. How I can retrieve it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Currently not possible.
I added an issue for this a long time ago which still hasn't been resolved: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=407